# Considering only 3D points, wouldn't this naive approach to the "smallest enclosing ball" be good enough?

Tags: c#, algorithm, computational-geometry

Lets use C# in our example.

```
public class Sphere
{
    public Point Center { get; set; }
    public float Radius { get; set; }

    public Sphere(IEnumerable<Point> points)
    {
        Point first = points.First();
        Point vecMaxZ = first;
        Point vecMinZ = first;
        Point vecMaxY = first;
        Point vecMinY = first;
        Point vecMinX = first;
        Point vecMaxX = first;

        foreach (Point current in points)
        {
            if (current.X < vecMinX.X)
            {
                vecMinX = current;
            }
            if (current.X > vecMaxX.X)
            {
                vecMaxX = current;
            }
            if (current.Y < vecMinY.Y)
            {
                vecMinY = current;
            }
            if (current.Y > vecMaxY.Y)
            {
                vecMaxY = current;
            }
            if (current.Z < vecMinZ.Z)
            {
                vecMinZ = current;
            }
            if (current.Z > vecMaxZ.Z)
            {
                vecMaxZ = current;
            }
        }

        //the lines bellow assure at least 2 points sit on the surface of the sphere.
        //I'm pretty sure the algorithm is solid so far, unless I messed up the if/elses.
        //I've been over this, looking at the variables and the if/elses and they all
        //seem correct, but our own errors are the hardest to spot,
        //so maybe there's something wrong here.
        float diameterCandidateX = vecMinX.Distance(vecMaxX);
        float diameterCandidateY = vecMinY.Distance(vecMaxY);
        float diameterCandidateZ = vecMinZ.Distance(vecMaxZ);
        Point c;
        float r;
        if (diameterCandidateX > diameterCandidateY)
        {
            if (diameterCandidateX > diameterCandidateZ)
            {
                c = vecMinX.Midpoint(vecMaxX);
                r = diameterCandidateX / 2f;
            }
            else
            {
                c = vecMinZ.Midpoint(vecMaxZ);
                r = diameterCandidateZ / 2f;
            }
        }
        else if (diameterCandidateY > diameterCandidateZ)
        {
            c = vecMinY.Midpoint(vecMaxY);
            r = diameterCandidateY / 2f;
        }
        else
        {
            c = vecMinZ.Midpoint(vecMaxZ);
            r = diameterCandidateZ / 2f;
        }

        //the lines bellow look for points outside the sphere, and if one is found, then:
        //1 let dist be the distance from the stray point to the current center
        //2 let diff be the equal to dist - radius
        //3 radius will then the increased by half of diff.
        //4 a vector with the same direction as the stray point but with magnitude equal to diff is found
        //5 the current center is moved by half the vector found in the step above.
        //
        //the stray point will now be included
        //and, I would expect, the relationship between the center and other points will be mantained:
        //if distance from p to center = r / k,
        //then new distance from p to center' = r' / k,
        //where k doesn't change from one equation to the other.
        //this is where I'm wrong. I cannot figure out how to mantain this relationship.
        //clearly, I'm moving the center by the wrong amount, and increasing the radius wrongly too.
        //I've been over this problem for so much time, I cannot think outside the box.
        //my whole world is the box. The box and I are one.
        //maybe someone from outside my world (the box) could tell me where my math is wrong, please.
        foreach (Point current in points)
        {
            float dist = current.Distance(c);
            if (dist > r)
            {
                float diff = dist - r;
                r += diff / 2f;
                float scaleFactor = diff / current.Length();
                Point adjust = current * scaleFactor;
                c += adjust / 2f;
            }
        }
        Center = c;
        Radius = r;
    }

    public bool Contains(Point point) => Center.Distance(point) <= Radius;

    public override string ToString() => $"Center: {Center}; Radius: {Radius}";
}

public class Point
{
    public float X { get; set; }
    public float Y { get; set; }
    public float Z { get; set; }

    public Point(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }

    public float LengthSquared() => X * X + Y * Y + Z * Z;

    public float Length() => (float) Math.Sqrt(X * X + Y * Y + Z * Z);

    public float Distance(Point another)
    {
        return (float) Math.Sqrt(
            (X - another.X) * (X - another.X)
          + (Y - another.Y) * (Y - another.Y)
          + (Z - another.Z) * (Z - another.Z));
    }

    public float DistanceSquared(Point another)
    {
        return (X - another.X) * (X - another.X)
             + (Y - another.Y) * (Y - another.Y)
             + (Z - another.Z) * (Z - another.Z);
    }

    public Point Perpendicular()
    {
        return new Point(-Y, X, Z);
    }

    public Point Midpoint(Point another)
    {
        return new Point(
            (X + another.X) / 2f,
            (Y + another.Y) / 2f,
            (Z + another.Z) / 2f);
    }

    public override string ToString() => $"({X}, {Y}, {Z})";
    public static Point operator +(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        return new Point(p1.X + p2.X, p1.Y + p2.Y, p1.Z + p2.Z);
    }

    public static Point operator *(Point p1, float v)
    {
        return new Point(p1.X * v, p1.Y * v, p1.Z * v);
    }

    public static Point operator /(Point p1, float v)
    {
        return new Point(p1.X / v, p1.Y / v, p1.Z / v);
    }
}

//Note: this class is here so I can be able to solve the problems suggested by
//Eric Lippert.
public class Line
{
    private float coefficient;
    private float constant;

    public Line(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        float deltaY = p2.Y - p1.Y;
        float deltaX = p2.X - p1.X;
        coefficient = deltaY / deltaX;
        constant = coefficient * -p1.X + p1.Y;
    }

    public Point FromX(float x)
    {
        return new Point(x, x * coefficient + constant, 0);
    }

    public Point FromY(float y)
    {
        return new Point((y - constant) / coefficient, y, 0);
    }

    public Point Intersection(Line another)
    {
        float x = (another.constant - constant) / (coefficient - another.coefficient);
        float y = FromX(x).Y;

        return new Point(x, y, 0);
    }
}
```

Can I safely assume this will run at least just as fast as the fancy algorithms out there that usually consider, for robustness sake, the possibility of the Points having any number of dimensions, from 2 to anything, like 1000 or 10,000 dimensions.

I only need it for 3 dimensions, never more and never less than that. Since I have no academic degree on computer science (or any degree for that matter, I'm a highschool sophomore), I have difficulties in analyzing algorithms for performance and resource consumption. So my question basically is: Is my "smallest enclosing sphere for dumbs" algoritm good in performance and resource consumption when compared with the fancy ones? Is there a point where my algorithm breaks while the professional ones don't, meaning it performs so bad it will cause noticeable loss (like, if I have too many points).

**EDIT 1:** I editted the code because it made no sense at all (I was hungry, it was 4pm and I haven't eaten all day). This one makes more sense I think, not sure if it's correct though. The original question stands: If this one solves the problem, does it do it well enough to compete with the stardard professional algorithms in case we know in advance that all points have 3 dimensions?

**EDIT 2:** Now I'm pretty sure the performance is bad, and I lost all hope of implementing a naive algorithm to find the smallest enclosing sphere. I just want to make something that work. Please, check the latest update.

**EDIT 3:** Doesn't work either. I quit.

**EDIT 4:** Finally, after, I don't know... some 5 hours. I figured it out. Jesus Christ. This one works. Could someone tell me about the performance issue? Is it really bad compared to the professional algorithms? What lines can I change to make it better? Is there a point where it breaks? Remember, I will always use it for 3D points.

**EDIT 5:** I learned from Bychenko the previous algorithm still didn't work. I slept on this issue, and this is my new version of the algorithm. I know it doesn't work, and I have a good clue where it is wrong, could anyone please tell why those particular calculations are wrong and how to fix them? I'm inclined to think this has something to do with trigonometry. My assumptions don't hold true for Euclidean space, because I can't stop seeing vectors as real numbers instead
of sets of real numbers that, in my case, I use to pin-point a location in Euclidean space. I'm pretty sure I'm missing some sine or cosine somewhere in the last loop (of course, not exactly sine or cosine, but the equivalent in cartesian coordinates, since we don't know any angles.

**Addendum to EDIT 5:** About the problems proposed by Eric Lippert:
(1) argh too trivial :p
(2) I will do it for the circle first; I will add a class Line for that.

```
Point a, b, c; //they are not collinear
Point midOfAB = a.Midpoint(b);
Point midOfBC = b.Midpoint(c);

//multiplying the vector by a scalar as I do bellow doesn't matter right?
Point perpendicularToAB = midOfAB.Perpendicular() * 3;
Point perpendicularToBC = midOfBC.Perpendicular() * 3;

Line bisectorAB = new Line(perpendicularToAB, midOfAB);
Line bisectorBC = new Line(perpendicularToBC, midOfBC);

Point center = bisectorAB.Intersection(bisectorBC);
float distA = center.Distance(a);
float distB = center.Distance(b);
float distC = center.Distance(c);

if(distA == distB && distB == distC)
    //it works (spoiler alert: it doesn't)
else
    //you're a failure, programmer, pick up your skate and practice some ollies
```

Comment: Your fourth program is plainly wrong. Sorry.  Try `var points = new [] { new Point(1, 0, 0), new Point(2, 0, 0), new Point(0,0,0) };var s = new Sphere(points); Console.WriteLine(s);`  result: NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN.

Comment: Your problem here is methodological, not mathematical. You're writing a program without having a solid, proven mathematical model, and without any test cases.  Don't write programs by writing something wrong and tinkering; design the program to be clearly correct by design and construct it using good engineering principles. **Start by writing the test cases**. Dozens of them. Make sure you know what the output of the program *should* be, and you'll find it a lot easier to know when you've got something wrong.

Comment: Also, your idea of trying to solve the problem in the smaller case of three dimensions is a good one. But as my test case shows, **you have not even solved it correctly for colinear points**. Get the **one dimensional** case right first. Then the two-dimensional case.  Only then move on to the 3-d case.

Comment: Thank you. Believe it or not, I tried. I have no formation though, I'm an amateur, currently a highschool sophomore. I'm not over this one. I will get it solved. Even if I get the worst algorithm in the history of algorithm performance, I will keep trying. Thank you for getting interested in my thread too. I will work on this by the moring. Also, by the way, I always heard about "testing units" and all that, but I don't really know what they are yet.

Comment: First off, it's good that you're not discouraged. That said, you've chosen a problem that is both tricky and well-studied. "Unit tests" are tests intended to verify the correctness of a particular portion of a program. So, for example, to test your Sphere constructor you would choose several sets of points where you have worked out the answer by hand, and then write a little program that verifies that all those cases work. It should complain loudly if one of them does not, so that you can debug it.

Comment: Regarding your fifth edit: Yes it is possible to do that: find the center of the minimal bounding sphere and then do a translation transformation of the center to the origin.  Unfortunately, find the center of the minimal bounding sphere is exactly the problem you are trying to solve!

Comment: Let's take a step back. Can you solve the following two easier problems?  (1) Given the center and radius of a sphere, and a set of points, return a bool that indicates whether the points are all in the sphere. (2) Given four non-coplanar points in 3-space, there is exactly one sphere that has all four on its surface. What is the center of that sphere? Solve those two problems correctly first.  Now can you solve a third problem: (3) given a set of points, determine all possible subsets of size four with non-coplanar points.  You can put those three sub-problems together to solve your problem.

Comment: (And if you are struggling with the four-points-on-the-surface problem, try instead solving first three non-colinear points on the surface of a circle.)

Comment: @EricLippertI tried non-collinear points and a circle that crosses all of them. I failed. the problem is trivial abstractly. I failed at translating it to code.

Comment: You are discovering a fundamental truth: coding *correctly* is surprisingly hard. But it gets easier with practice. Keep taking steps back. Remember, coding is about working with abstractions, so build *powerful* abstractions that are *clearly correct* and then work with them. You are on the right track with your point and line abstractions. Keep beefing them up, and test them as you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but your algorithm is *wrong*. It doesn't solve the problem.

Counter example (3 points):

```
A = (0, 0, 0) - closest to origin    (0)
B = (3, 3, 0) - farthest from origin (3 * sqrt(2) == 4.2426...) 
C = (4, 0, 0)
```

your naive algorithm declares that the sphere has center at

```
P = (3 / sqrt(2), 3 / sqrt(2), 0)
```

and radius

```
R = 3 / sqrt(2)
```

and you can see that the point `C = (4, 0, 0)` is *beyond* the sphere

**Edit** the updated (but naive) algorithm is still wrong.

Counter example (3 points):

```
 A = (0, 0, 0)
 B = (1, 2, 0)
 C = (4, 1, 0)
```

according the algorithm the sphere has its center at

```
 P = (2, 1, 0)
```

with radius

```
 R = sqrt(5)
```

and you can see that the sphere is not a *minimal* (smallest) one.

**Nth Edit** you still have an *incorrect* algorithm. When exploring *gray zone* (you know the problem, but partially, with holes) it's a good practice to invest into testing automatition. As you should know, in case of triangle all the vertexes should be on the sphere; let's validate your the solution on this fact:

```
  public static class SphereValidator {
    private static Random m_Random = new Random();

    private static String Validate() {
      var triangle = Enumerable
        .Range(0, 3)
        .Select(i => new Point(m_Random.Next(100), m_Random.Next(100), m_Random.Next(100)))
        .ToArray();

      Sphere solution = new Sphere(triangle);
      double tolerance = 1.0e-5;

      for (int i = 0; i < triangle.Length; ++i) {
        double r = triangle[i].Distance(solution.Center);

        if (Math.Abs(r - solution.Radius) > tolerance) {
          return String.Format("Counter example\r\n  A: {0}\r\n  B: {1}\r\n  C: {2}\r\n  expected distance to \"{3}\": {4}; actual R {5}",
            triangle[0], triangle[1], triangle[2], (char) ('A' + i), r, solution.Radius);
        }
      }

      return null;
    }

    public static String FindCounterExample(int attempts = 10000) {
      for (int i = 0; i < attempts; ++i) {
        String result = Validate();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
          Console.WriteLine(result);

        return;
      }

      Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Yes! All {0} tests passed!", attempts));
    }
  }
```

I've just run the code above and got:

```
  Counter example
    A: (3, 30, 9)
    B: (1, 63, 40)
    C: (69, 1, 16)
    expected distance to "A": 35.120849609375; actual R 53.62698
```

Comment: Not only that, as I was having a snack I noticed it doesn't solve the problem for many cases. I'll try to correct it.

Comment: could you take a look at it now?

Comment: @FinnTheHuman: take just *three* points in *2 D* (let z coordinate be zero). The problem is to find out a circumsribed circle for triangle; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle; please notice, that the formula is not that simple.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I'll have to copy paste something I don't fully understand then... I hate doing this, unless when absolutely necessary.

Comment: @FinnTheHuman: why copy+paste? Just google "smallest enclosing circle algorithm" for instance http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/ga/slides4b.pdf

Comment: because now that I realize how complex the problem is surely I can't come up with a naive algorithm that would solve the problem and still do well in performance. So I have to copy paste one of those esoteric algorithms. I know realize at least 2 points must sit on the surface of my sphere, and I can't naively do that in only one loop. I would have to create lists and buckets and all kind of stuff. i'd better just copy paste the of the professional and translate them from C++ to Java (That is the actual language of my project, the example was in C# because it's a much more elegant language)

Comment: I hate to bother you once more, but there's no one else in this thread... Would you please check it again, sir. Now all I want to know is if it works. And if it does, it probably is the Computational Geometry equivalent of BubbleSort's retarded cousin.

Comment: It works now. Maybe now it can be checked for performance, and I'd love some hints on which lines could be improved. I'm so tired. It's 11:15pm. I don't know how to calculate how efficient an algorithm is (that O(n), O(log n stuff. All I want to know is if my naive approach to the problem is really horrible compared to the standarized solutions.

Comment: @FinnTheHuman: I'm sorry for bringing bad news. The algorithm *doesn't work properly*. I suggest investing into *tests automatition* (see my edit above)

Comment: I did not know the case for triangles should be treated like that... damn T-T
does it work for all other number of points except 3? cause then I could write a special case for 3 points.

Comment: @FinnTheHuman: If you add inner points into the triangle counter example, you'll get a counter example for 4 points, 5 points etc.
Triangle is just a good touch stone: it's flat (and so you can easily visualize the solution in order to find out pesky errors); 
it's simple enough to compute the sphere manually (e.g. `R = (a * b * c) / (4 * S)` where S - trinagle's square and `a, b, c` are sides' lengths). 
Finally, triangle case is very convenient to write a smoke test (all three triangle's vertexes must be on the sphere, providing that the triangle is not a *degenerated one*).

Answer (score 0):

For a crude approximation, compute the Axis-Aligned Bounding Box, then the bounding sphere of that box (same center, diameter = √(W² + H² + D²) ).

You can refine by computing the largest distance from that center.